# How to fix DataFrame function issues in PySpark - Py4JJavaError

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create and analyze dataframe in PySpark and in Notebook.

Below are my codes in Jupyter Notebook.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .master("local") \
   .appName("Neural Network Model") \
   .config("spark.executor.memory", "6gb") \
   .getOrCreate()
```

I was able to start Spark Session.

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('John', 56, 80)])
print(df1.dtypes)
print(df1)
print(df1.show())
```

I was able to create df1, dataframe, but Somehow, I got error message when I am trying to use data frame function in df1.show()

> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         2 print(df1.dtypes)
>         3 print(df1)
>   ----> 4 print(df1.show())
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o501.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 9.0 (TID 22, localhost, executor driver):
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:97)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:108)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)

Could you help me to fix this issues?  I am not sure if it is system issue or my codes.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

`df1.show()` just show the content of dataframe. It's a function that returns Unit (it does not return a value). So `print(df1.show())` would fail (in Databricks notebook returns None)

If you want to see the content of df1, just need to do

```py
df1.show()
```

without print()

This is actually the implementation of show():

```py
def show(): Unit = show(20)

def show(numRows: Int): Unit = show(numRows, truncate = true)

def show(numRows: Int, truncate: Boolean): Unit = if (truncate) {
   println(showString(numRows, truncate = 20))
 } else {
   println(showString(numRows, truncate = 0))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your your feedback. I also tried df1.show().  I got the same error message.  I also check if it is only for .show(). When I tried df1.collect(), I also got the same error messages.  I am concerned that it is due to some system set up.  I set up the Spark environment using jdk1.8.0_201, and spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.  And I integrated Spark with Jupyter notebook.